# Is torchvision.datasets.cifar.CIFAR10 a list or not?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, torchvision

When I try to figure out what is inside torchvision.datasets.cifar.CIFAR10, I did some simple code

```
trainset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True,
                                    download=True, transform=transform)
print(trainset[1])
print(trainset[:10])
print(type(trainset))
```

However, I got some error when I try

```
print(trainset[:10])
```

The error info is

```
TypeError: Cannot handle this data type
```

I am wondering why I can use `trainset[1]`, but not `trainset[:10]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slicing isnt supported by CIFAR10, which is why you are getting that error. If you want the first 10 you will have to do this instead:

```py
print([trainset[i] for i in range(10)])
```

---

## More Info

The main reason why you can index an instance of CIFAR10 class is because the class implements `__getitem__()` function.

So, when you call `trainset[i]` you are essentially calling `trainset.__getitem__(i)`

Now, in python3, slicing expressions is also handled through `__getitem__()` where the slicing expression is passed to `__getitem__()` as a slice object.

So, `trainset[2:10]` is equivalent to `trainset.__getitem__(slice(2, 10))`

And since the two different types of objects being passed to `__getitem__`
are expected to do entirely different things, you have to handle them explicitly.

Unfortunately it isnt, as you can see from the `__getitem__` method implementation of CIFAR10 class:

```py
def __getitem__(self, index):
    if self.train:
        img, target = self.train_data[index], self.train_labels[index]
    else:
        img, target = self.test_data[index], self.test_labels[index]

    # doing this so that it is consistent with all other datasets
    # to return a PIL Image
    img = Image.fromarray(img)

    if self.transform is not None:
        img = self.transform(img)

    if self.target_transform is not None:
        target = self.target_transform(target)

    return img, target
```

Comment: exactly, I do tried it before. I am just curious what is the type of torchvision.datasets.cifar.CIFAR10 ?

Comment: added more details

Comment: Oh, I mean this explanation makes a lot of sense to me now, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In a addition to https://stackoverflow.com/a/45226879/7924573 entrophys answer I would suggest using **torch.utils.data.dataset.random_split** e.g. this: way:

```py
train_size = int(0.8*len(dataset))
test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
lengths = [train_size, test_size]
train_dataset, valid_dataset = torch.utils.data.dataset.random_split(dataset, lengths)
trainloader = DataLoader(train_data, 
  batch_size=args.train_batch,  
  shuffle=True, 
  num_workers=args.nThreads, 
  pin_memory=True)
validloader = DataLoader(valid_data, 
  batch_size=args.train_batch,  
  shuffle=True, 
  num_workers=args.nThreads, 
  pin_memory=True)
```

source: https://yimjiyoung.github.io/2020/02/13/How-to-split-dataset-into-train-and-validation-set-in-pytorch/